# Python - Automating Chrome to start and enter URL in address bar using autoit

Tags: python-3.x, autoit

I'm new to AutoIt and its library in Python *PyAutoIt*. I want my Python script to open Chrome browser, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to go to the address bar of the Chrome browser, type `https://www.yahoo.com` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Here's my code which I tried to execute:

```
import autoit

autoit.run("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
autoit.send( "!d^ahttps://www.yahoo.com{ENTER}" )
```

Problem in this code is that it is writing the URL on my Python IDE also while writing it to the browser.

Just to mention that `!d` means <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and `^a` means <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

OS: *Windows 10 x64*
Python IDE: *Anaconda Spyder*
PyAutoIt Version: *0.5*

Comment: You run `chrome.exe`, and without waiting for the window to show, you send a string of actions. I doubt you would do that manually of sending actions to a window that is not showing. View the example at the bottom of the [pyautoit](https://github.com/jacexh/pyautoit) front website page about automating notepad.

Comment: You are absolutely correct @michael_health, I'm editing the question to add `autoit.win_wait_active("New Tab", timeout=10)` to the code, which would set the chrome browser window as the active window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a bit of research on what *michael_health* said in the comment and found the following solution to the problem:

```
import autoit
import time

google_chrome_pid = autoit.run('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -incognito', show_flag=3) # run in incognito mode, start maximized
autoit.win_wait_active("New Tab", timeout=10) # active window 
time.sleep(3)
autoit.opt("SendKeyDelay", 100) # Slow down typing to 100 milliseconds
autoit.send("!dhttps://www.yahoo.com")
time.sleep(2)
autoit.send("{ENTER}")
```